# XSLT tokenize - capturing the separators

Tags: xslt, tokenize, separator

here is a piece of code in XSL which tokenizes a text into fragments separated by interpunction and similar characters. I'd like to ask if there is a possibility to somehow capture the strings by which the text was tokenized, for example the comma or dot etc.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt err fn" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="GENERUJ">
    <TEXT>
        <xsl:variable name="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(unparsed-text(@filename, 'UTF-8'))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($text, '(\s+(&quot;|\(|\[|\{))|((&quot;|,|;|:|\s\-|\)|\]|\})\s+)|((\.|\?|!|;)&quot;?\s*)' )">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(.)&gt;0">
                    <FRAGMENT>
                        <CONTENT>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </CONTENT>
                        <LENGTH>
                            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(.)"/>
                        </LENGTH>
                    </FRAGMENT>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <FRAGMENT_COUNT>
                        <xsl:value-of select="last()-1"/>
                    </FRAGMENT_COUNT>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </TEXT>
</xsl:template>
```

As you see the constructed tags CONTENTS, LENGTH, I'd like to add one called SEPARATOR if you know what I mean. I couldnt find any answer to this on the internet and I'm just a beginner with xsl transformations so I'm looking for a quick solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you include some simplified sample input and expected output? As it stands, your question is not sufficiently clear.

Comment: General point: don't use `<xsl:variable name="x"><xsl:value-of select="s"/></xsl:variable>`. Instead use `<xsl:variable name="x" select="s"/>`. It's not only less verbose, it's also much more efficient.

Comment: Hmm.. if it helps the input (variable "text") would be a textfile in the form `Blah blah blah, blah blah (blah blah) blah.` and the desired output something like `<TEXT><FRAGMENT><CONTENT>Blah blah blah</CONTENT><LENGTH>14</LENGTH><SEPARATOR>,</SEPARATOR></FRAGMENT>...` and so on... and Michael, I tried to use your suggestion, but if you scroll left there is a `disable-output-escaping="yes"` attribute and it gives me an error vhen I put it to the `xsl:variable` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tokenize() function doesn't allow you to discover what the separators were. If you need to know, you will need to use `xsl:analyze-string` instead. If you use the same regex as for tokenize(), this passes the "tokens" to the `xsl:non-matching-substring` instruction and the "separators" to the `xsl:matching-substring` instruction.

Comment: Thank you very much, after a few hours of trying to figure out how `xsl:analyze-string` works I got kinda what I wanted.