# Access matched pattern within XSL tokenize

Tags: xslt, xpath

Suppose I have the following variable

```
<xsl:variable name="randomString" select="'COLUMN1 == 400 or COLUMN1 == 5 and COLUMN2 != 3'" />
```

Is there any convenient way to access the matched pattern within the tokenize() function e.g. using this

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($randomString, 'and|or')">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('not(', current(), ')')" />
  <!-- How do I access the matched pattern? -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or do I have to use a custom template like the one I have found here http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.77.0/doc/lib/str.tokenize.keep.delimiters.html

Comment: When you say "the matched pattern", you're talking about the `and|or` separator pattern, right? You want to know whether it was `and` or `or` in a given instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325082/xslt-tokenize-capturing-the-separators

Comment: Exactly @LarsH - I want to go on depending on if the `and` or `or` matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to retrieve the matched separator. "The separators themselves are not returned." (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)

A workaround could be, tokenizing with `or` as a separator in an outer loop, then tokenizing with `and` as a separator in an inner loop. Then you would always know which separators you were dealing with, based on where in the loops you are.

Another approach would be to use `analyze-string()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10329602/423105).